# Verifying NLP prediction

Tags: natural-language

In NLP multi-label classification

How can we verify multi-label classification is right?

I mean I want to highlight the words Machine used to give me the results I got.

an example on technical support labels

> When you use a Dell mouse to click or select an icon, window, folder
>   or other object in Windows the computer produces a clicking or other
>   similar sound that you can hear through your speakers. If the clicking
>   sound produced by the computer disturbs you or others in the office,
>   disable the sound in Windows and enjoy a quieter and more productive
>   computing experience. Click “Start,” then “Control Panel.” In the
>   “Adjust your computer’s settings” window, click “Hardware and Sound.”
>   Click “Change System Sounds” underneath the Sound link in the
>   "Hardware and Sound" window to open the Sounds window. Click the
>   “Sounds” tab. Scroll down to and select the “Start Navigation” option
>   in the Windows Explorer section of the Program Events list box. Click
>   the drop-down list labeled “Windows Navigation Start” and select
>   “None.” Click “Apply,” then the “OK” button. Close the "Hardware and
>   Sound" window. Tip You can also open the Sounds window by
>   right-clicking the speaker icon in the taskbar and then clicking
>   “Sounds” on the pop-up menu.

predictive model can give these labels

**Operating System Problem**

**Sound Problem**

**Hardware Problem**

I want to know what are the words the influenced machine to choose these labels.

If the text is so big, I cant read it all to verify if the labels were correct or not.

I want the machine to highligh/select/ or any other way tell me what made it choose these labels

Something like this would be good

> When you use a `Dell mouse` to click or select an icon, window, folder
>   or other object in `Windows` the computer produces a clicking or other
>   similar `sound that you can hear through your speakers`. If the clicking
>   sound produced by the computer disturbs you or others in the office,
>   `disable the sound` in Windows and enjoy a `quieter` and more productive
>   computing experience. Click “Start,” then “Control Panel.” In the
>   “Adjust your computer’s settings” window, click “`Hardware and Sound`.”
>   Click “Change System Sounds” underneath the Sound link in the
>   "Hardware and Sound" window to open the Sounds window. Click the
>   “Sounds” tab. Scroll down to and select the “Start Navigation” option
>   in the Windows Explorer section of the Program Events list box. Click
>   the drop-down list labeled “Windows Navigation Start” and select
>   “None.” Click “Apply,” then the “OK” button. Close the "Hardware and
>   Sound" window. Tip You can also open the Sounds window by
>   right-clicking the speaker icon in the taskbar and then clicking
>   “Sounds” on the pop-up menu.

Comment: Determining "what a model is looking at" is an entire field of research, I don't think it can be succinctly answered here. See for example [this article](https://ai.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html) about how a neural network can learn the relevant parts of an image.

Comment: Try searching for something along the lines of: "visualizing network weights"

Comment: @FransRodenburg Thanks heaps

Comment: Not all models are black boxes or transparent the same way. Decision trees for instance, are famous for being quite interpretable, while neural networks are a lot harder to interpret. Coul you tell us in the question what models are you using in the classification task? I see the other comments talk about neural networks. It's that what you are using?

Comment: @armando I see now that it was not explicitly stated in the question, but I assumed it because it seems to be the dominating strategy to NLP.

Comment: @FransRodenburg, well yes they are by far the most powerful, but neural networks are not necessarily the best approach for everything in NLP and certainly not the simplest to implement/understand, much less to interpret.